# Pars url contain # with Iris framework

Tags: go, url

The microsoft graph authentication response has a url containing # character like below

`http://localhost:8000/auth/outlook#code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

The problem is to parsing this URL by iris framework and retrieve the code. How should i define the URL structure and how to pars the full URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragment identifiers are processed purely on the client. They are never sent to the server in the first place. Therefore, you *cannot* process them on the server.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html here's a doc for the curious